# Define integer depending on global integer

Tags: c++, global-variables

I'm trying to make a 5x5 2d array for a convolution filter and I would like the sum of all the values stored in a define.

```
int foo [5][5] = {
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1
};

define bar = /* sum of all the values in foo */
```

Is this possible or not?

Comment: By define you mean a preprocessor #define? Then that is not possible.

Comment: Otherwise, https://godbolt.org/g/kZpoeV.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `const` variable.

I would make a function to count values and return the sum. Something like this:

```
int matrix_value_count(const int *matrix_ptr, int row_number, int col_number) {
    int sum = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < row_number * col_number; i++)
        sum = sum + *(matrix_ptr + i);
    return sum;
}
```

Of course it would be better to use `template` but I think it's a bit too much for start.
To execute this function change the last line of your code to:

```
const int bar = matrix_value_count(foo, 5, 5);
```

That should work.